# How to retrieve row and column names from data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have generated a correlation matrix from a dataframe using pandas.corr:

```
cmat = sub1.corr()

cmat
Out[75]: 
          CESI001   CESI002   CESI003   CESI004
CESI001  1.000000  0.829723  0.046925  0.074475
CESI002  0.829723  1.000000  0.066766  0.073181
CESI003  0.046925  0.066766  1.000000 -0.098427
CESI004  0.074475  0.073181 -0.098427  1.000000
```

What I'm trying to do is generate a new dataframe consisting of [row, column, value] where the cell value meets some criteria. I have succeeded in retrieving the matching cell values:

```
for i2,r2 in cmat.iterrows():
for item in cmat[i2]:
    if ((item > 0.3) and (item < 0.9)):
        print (item)
```

This correctly produces:

```
0.829723365019
0.829723365019
```

However, I can't work backwards from there to retrieve the row and column names. I've tried .loc, .columname and several other approaches I read about here. I'm getting that Python is more about operating on the whole data frame. Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `stack` to line up rows and columns
- `query` to filter what you need

---

```
cmat.stack().to_frame('item').query('.3 < item < .9')
```

[image]